# Find line by text and delete from that line to other in bash

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

Using a linux bash or command line, i need to find certain string in a file and delete that line and the lines until white space.

My file:

```
geo_ws:
    resource: "@GeoWSBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

mappublic:
    resource: "@MapPublicBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /map/ws

webpublic:
    resource: "@WebPublicBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /public

map:
    resource: "@MapBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /map

geo:
    resource: "@GeoBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /geo

ws:
    resource: "@WSBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /ws

web:
    resource: "@WebBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

So i need to find i.e "map:", and clear all those 4 lines until next white line.

I've tried using seed, but i just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty record separator indicates that records are delimited by blank lines:

```
$ awk -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n' '!/^map/' file
geo_ws:
    resource: "@GeoWSBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

webpublic:
    resource: "@WebPublicBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /public

geo:
    resource: "@GeoBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /geo

ws:
    resource: "@WSBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /ws

web:
    resource: "@WebBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

Comment: Note this will make two newlines at the end of the file which were not there to begin with(not sure if OP cares)

Comment: The output is alright, but don't know how to override the file with those changes.

Comment: @jonyjm: Like this: `awk -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n' '!/^map/' file > tmpfile && mv tmpfile file`

Answer (score 2):

Using gawk

```
awk -vRS= '{ORS=RT?RT:"\n"}!/^map/' file

geo_ws:
    resource: "@GeoWSBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

webpublic:
    resource: "@WebPublicBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /public

geo:
    resource: "@GeoBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /geo

ws:
    resource: "@WSBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /ws

web:
    resource: "@WebBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

Comment: What awk are you using and what system are you on ?